# Django - Two different join statements on the same table

Tags: python, django

In a Django project as models I have something like that:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u"Name"), max_length=100)

INPUT_TYPES = (('U', _(u"User")), ('A', _(u"Administrator")))
class CompanyData(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='data')
    input_type = models.CharField(_(u"Input type"), max_length=2,
                                  choices=INPUT_TYPES)
    active = models.BooleanField(_(u"Active"))
    datafield_1 = models.CharField(_(u"Data field 1"), max_length=100)
    datafield_2 = models.CharField(_(u"Data field 2"), max_length=100)
    datafield_3 = models.CharField(_(u"Data field 3"), max_length=100)
```

The company data can be entered as a user or as an administrator.

It is possible to make searches on companies. The searches can be made without dealing with the input type but I want to exclude inactive company (no matter if it was set inactive by a user or by an administrator). I have tried a query like that:

```
Company.objects.filter(data__data_1='query string'
                       ).exclude(Q(data__active=False))
```

But if one of the data input is active and match the query string it will return the company even if the other data input is inactive. I have tried to sophisticate the request by forcing the input type but I have found no manner to force Django to make two different join statements on the CompanyData table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you have hit on one of the weaknesses of Django's ORM. It is not possible to perform this sort of query with object syntax; you will need to resort to [raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) in order to accomplish this.

Comment: I feared this answer. In comparison to what I have presented the model and the search fields are much more complicated. Dynamic raw query will be awful. But if there is no other mean I'll try to do a mix... Despite that thank you.